# Hard defining decimal places

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to read a table column for decimal places, and apply that decimal to an output (regardless of trailing 0s).  Is there a way to do that within SQL?

The loose table is what I have here.  I was able to find some examples that included hard defining the decimals, but I'm wondering if I could do so dynamically based upon the related data.

[image]

Comment: Please update your question to include table definitions (in the form of create table), sample data (in the form of inserts) and expected results.

Comment: Presentation of resultsets is a function of the consumer of that resultset. Numeric columns are stored in a non-readable binary format in the database. Your goal is best addressed in the tool consuming your resultset. But you can't really accomplish your goal in tsql - a specific column has a fixed datatype. You could convert the value to string and dynamically format the value of each row - but not suggested. This has a big [XY smell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: My question revolves more around how do I show this automatically formatted as specified within Excel.

Comment: And yet the only tag you used is "sql-server" and posted on dba. You are not reaching the appropriate audience IMO. Excel supports conditional formatting, does it not?

Answer (score 1):

I 100% agree with all the comments to your question, but I thought this was a simple and fun one to try to solve so I wrote the following up anyway, and you can choose to use it or not.

If I understand your question and schema correctly, you want to display the `Number` field padded with 0s on the end such that the `Decimals` column equaled the total number of digits on the right side of the decimal in the `Number`. I'm also assuming your `Number` column is a text based data type (such as `VARCHAR`) otherwise your output would already be padded with the pre-defined number of 0s based on it's non-integer numeric data type.

This is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT Decimals, Number + REPLICATE('0', Decimals - (LEN(Number) - CHARINDEX('.', Number))) AS NumberWithZeros
FROM BryanTest
```

Which outputs the following results:

[image: Query Results]

This uses the [`REPLICATE()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) of SQL Server to generate the number of 0s needed based on the number in the `Decimals` column minus the number of digits to the right of the decimal in the `Number` column.

For reference, this is the `CREATE` script for my schema used in the above example:

```
CREATE TABLE BryanTest (Decimals INT, Number VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO BryanTest (Decimals, Number)
VALUES (3, '1.23'), (4, '1.56'), (5, '1.563')
```